# jquery ejecutar una funcion luego de un cierto numero de caracteres

Tags: jquery

hellos

Tengo dos textbox y la idea es que cuando escriba algo en el primer textbox y llegue a cierta cantidad de caracteres se ejecute una funcion

Este es el codigo que tengo en mente:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#codigoCompany").keyup(function () {
        var a = $("#codigoCompany").length;
        if (a => 4) {
            var nombre = $("#codigoCompany").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Facturas/buscarCodigo?nombre=' + nombre,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.status == "ok") {
                        $("#txtCliente").val(data.resultado);
                    } else {
                        alert("paso algo raro");
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    })
})
```

Pero no me funciona, no entiendo que pasa. Si hay alguna otra forma mas simple de poder hacer, favor de mencionar el metodo.
Muchas gracias

Gracias a la ayuda de la comunidad este codigo ya es funcional

lo que modifique fue esta linea de codigo

```
 var a = $("#codigoCompany").val().length;    

 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#codigoCompany").keyup(function () {
        var a = $("#codigoCompany").val().length;
        if (a => 4) {
            var nombre = $("#codigoCompany").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Facturas/buscarCodigo?nombre=' + nombre,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.status == "ok") {
                        $("#txtCliente").val(data.resultado);
                    } else {
                        alert("paso algo raro");
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Tal vez solo sea un error de tipeo. ¿Quizás quieres decir `a >= 4` en vez de `a => 4`? El uso de `=>` es otra sintaxis para definir funciones.

Comment: ok, lo intentare mas tarde, muchas gracias

Comment: Hola, además de lo que dijo César, en la linea 3 estás trayendo el atributo **length** del elemento **input** en vez del de su contenido. Corrigiendo esas dos cosas creo que debería funcionar.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por todas las sugerencias, ahora me ahorre un boton y aprendi mucho mas. Como observacion ahora se comporta como un autocomplete, no entiendo el por que, pero, no tengo quejas xD

Comment: Por favor lee [answer], la solución a tu duda no va en la misma pregunta, para eso dispones abajo del espacio de respuestas.

Comment: No entendi bien, pense que podia modificar el codigo que puse arriba para ya dejarlo totalmente funcional. la idea es que esta linea de codigo var a = $("#codigoCompany").length la modifique de esta manera var a = $("#codigoCompany").val().length y funciona como si fuera un autocomplete, aunque queria que hiciera la busqueda cuando tuviera 4 caracteres o mas, muchas gracias nuevamente

Comment: No, dispones de ese espacio para dejar la pregunta como estaba y en la parte inferior colocar la respuesta, para que de ese modo quien tenga un problema similar encuentre lo que ocurría y posterior como lo resolviste.

Answer (score 1):

Aqui te comparto este codigo que puede optimizar la solucion que encontraste

```js
var textbox = $("#codigoCompany"); 

 $(document).ready(function () {
    textbox.keyup(function () {
        if(textbox.val().length >= 4){
          console.log('Aqui colocar la funcion')
        }
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="codigoCompany">
```

Guardamos en la variable textbox el input, y con la misma variable le asignamos el evento keyup y la utilizamos para traer el valor del length del valor.